# Canvas cannot read gestures

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I use this [svelte-gestures](https://github.com/Rezi/svelte-gestures) library to read gestures, and I use it on canvas. I played with [svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/bb47278283564ed08e36677d8b43186c?version=3.38.2) provided by the library maker, and also tried it on my own [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=4.1.2), it's all working well.

But when I put it in my svelteKit local project, something happens, the canvas element refuses to read the gestures, and when I check in the developer tools, there is some additional styling that was added automatically to the canvas: `{ touch-action:none; user-select:none }`.

So I try to break down my project:

- Example 1: At first I thought that something because I nested my canvas inside div/section. But when I tested it, it works. There is no problem whatsoever.

```
    <section>
        <div>
            <canvas 
                width={300} 
                height={300}
                ></canvas>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    
    <style>
        canvas {
            border:solid;
        }
    </style>
```

- Example 2: I try to add 2 simple gestures, tap and swipe. And it not working, and there are additional style automatically added: `{ touch-action: auto }`. Even it's not `none`, it's still not working

```
    <script>
        import { swipe, tap } from 'svelte-gestures';
    
        function tapHandler() {
            console.log("tap")
            // not logging
        }
     
        function swipeHandler(event) {
            console.log("swipe")
            // also not logging
        }   
    </script>
    <section>
        <div>
            <canvas 
                width={300} 
                height={300}
                use:swipe={{ timeframe: 300, minSwipeDistance: 60 }} 
                on:swipe={swipeHandler}
                use:tap 
                on:tap={tapHandler}
                ></canvas>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <style>
        canvas {
            border:solid;
        }
    </style>
```

- Example 3: My original code (simplified), I added composed gestures to prevent press & hold registered as scrolling on mobile. It's still not working, even it's working properly on my REPL

```
    <script>
        import { swipe, tap, composedGesture, press, scroll, pan } from 'svelte-gestures';
    
        function tapHandler() {
            console.log("tap")
            // not logging
        }
     
        function swipeHandler(event) {
            console.log("swipe")
            // also not logging
        }   
       
        // this function prevent reading press & hold/swipe down as scrolling page
        function scrollPan(register) {
            const pressFns = register(press, {
            triggerBeforeFinished: true,
            spread: 10,
            timeframe: 100,
            });
            const scrollFns = register(scroll, { delay: 0 });
            const panFns = register(pan, { delay: 0 });
    
            return (activeEvents, event) => {
            pressFns.onMove(activeEvents, event) || event.pointerType !== 'touch'
                ? panFns.onMove(activeEvents, event)
                : scrollFns.onMove(activeEvents, event);
            };
        };
    
    </script>
    <section>
        <div>
            <canvas 
                width={300} 
                height={300}
                use:swipe={{ timeframe: 300, minSwipeDistance: 60 }} 
                on:swipe={swipeHandler}
                use:tap 
                on:tap={tapHandler}
                use:composedGesture={scrollPan}
                ></canvas>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <style>
        canvas {
            border:solid;
        }
    </style>
```

I also read the documentation that in svelteKit that says:
"if you use the Svelte kit, you already have a `global.d.ts` in src folder. Just add this line after"
`/// <reference types="@sveltejs/kit" />`

But my svelteKit project doesn't have `global.d.ts`, but `app.d.ts` so I put it there. But it is not solving my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem:

on mobile, the `<canvas>` sunk under the `body` and `html`, and actually, the `touch-action` and `user-select` must be set as `'none'`. So the user can't interact with the canvas, not even the first object selected in the inspector element select tool.

the solution:

- set the `body` and `html` element `pointer-events` to `'none'` and set the canvas `pointer-events` to `'all'`
- the `svelte gestures` library set the `touch-action` automatically as auto, so I have to set the `touchAction` option. for example: `on:tap={{touchAction='none'}}`